# Key-Value Coding When the Key is Occasionally Missing

Tags: objective-c, key-value-coding

Let's say I have the following:

```
NSDictionary *searchResults = @{
  @"results": @[
    @{@"employee": @"John Doe"},
    @{@"company": @"Doe Inc"},
    @{@"employee": @"Jane Doe"}
  ]
};
```

I want to use KVC to get all the employee names. I'd do it like so:

```
NSArray *names = [searchResults valueForKeyPath:@"results.employee"];
```

I'd expect to get two entries, but instead I get three:

```
(lldb) po [$searchResults valueForKeyPath:@"results.employee"]
<__NSArrayI 0x7fc59bd77840>(
John Doe,
<null>,
Jane Doe
)
```

If I enter a completely missing key, I'll get an array of only `NSNull`s:

```
(lldb) po [$searchResults valueForKeyPath:@"results.employee1"]
<__NSArrayI 0x7fc59bd739a0>(
<null>,
<null>,
<null>
)
```

Is there a keypath I can construct that only returns non-null values?